# Wordpress content not appearing in web browser

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

None of my content appears to be showing in a web browser. I created the website in Wordpress

I am not sure whether I am missing some vital code but it seems to display the logo and the 'Services' bar but otherwise my page appears to be empty

header.php:

```
</head>

<body class="">



    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="jump">

            <p><a href="#content">jump to content</a></p>

        </div>



            <div class="hud-content">

        <div id="content-container">

<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="/" title="Wild Lion Media">
            <img src="/wildlion/wp-content/themes/child/images/logo.png" width="95" height="120" alt="Wild Lion Media" title="Wild Lion Media" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <h1>
                    Wild Lion Media             
    </h1>

    <div id="hud-toggler">
        <ul>

            <li><a href="#" class="hud-toggle">Login / Register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="nav-home"><a href="/" title="Return to the Wild Lion Media home page">Home</a></li>
        <li id="nav-dandad"><a class="nav-item" href="/dandad" title="Wild Lion Media">Wild Lion Media</a>
            <div class="subnav">
    <ul class="subnav">
        <li><a href="/dandad/about" title="About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/dandad/events" title="Events">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="/dandad/join" title="Join">Join</a></li>
        <li><a href="/dandad/latest/news" title="Latest News">Latest</a></li>
        <li><a href="/dandad/partnerships" title="Partnerships">Partnerships</a></li>
        <li><a href="/dandad/white-pencil" title="White Pencil">White Pencil</a></li>
        <li class="feature">
            <p class="intro">Get your voice heard</p>
            <p>Wild Lion Media Membership: It&rsquo;s classy, exclusive, well connected &ndash; everything you could ask for from a private member&rsquo;s club. Ok, we don&rsquo;t have a pool on the roof, but just wait till you see the size of our archive.</p>
            <p class="readmore"><a href="/dandad/join" title="read more">Read More</a></p>
            <img src="#" width="167" height="167" alt="Nav Yellow Pencil" class="feature-pic"/>

            <ul class="feature-links">
                <li><a href="/dandad/join/individual-membership" title="Individual Membership">Individual<br />
                    Membership</a></li>
                <li><a href="/dandad/join/d-ad-education-network" title="Education Network">Education<br />
                    Network</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>      </li>
        <li id="nav-inspire"><a class="nav-item" href="/inspiration" title="Inspiration">Inspiration</a>
            <div class="subnav">
    <ul class="subnav">
        <li><a href="/inspiration/inspired-by" title="Inspired by&hellip;">Inspired by&hellip;</a></li>
        <li><a href="/inspiration/watch-and-listen" title="Watch &amp; Listen">Watch &amp; Listen</a></li>
        <li><a href="/inspiration/have-your-say" title="Have Your Say">Have Your Say</a></li>
        <li><a href="/inspiration/features-and-opinion" title="Features &amp; opinion">Features &amp; Opinion</a></li>
        <li><a href="/inspiration/profiles" title="Profile">Profiles</a></li>
        <li><a href="/inspiration/archives-and-collections" title="Archives &amp; Collections">Archives &amp; Collections</a></li>
        <li class="feature">
            <p class="intro">Wild Lion Media<br/>President&rsquo;s Lectures</p>
            <p>Chosen by the President of Wild Lion Media speakers represent the best in their creative fields and inspire discussion and debate.<br/></p>
            <p class="readmore"><a href="/dandad/events?series=President%E2%80%99s%20Lectures">Book your tickets</a></p>
            <img src="#" width="167" height="167" alt="President’s Lectures" class="feature-pic"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>      </li>
        <li id="nav-awards"><a class="nav-item" href="/awards" title="Awards">Awards</a>
            <div class="subnav">
    <ul class="subnav award-sections">
        <li>
            <p class="intro">Professional Awards</p>
            <p>Yellow Pencils are recognised the world over as a symbol of true creative achievement. Year on year the Wild Lion Media Annual showcases the very best work and continues to provide an unrivalled source of creative inspiration.</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/awards/professional" title="Professional">Professional</a></li>
                <li class="new"><a href="/awards/professional/2012" title="2012">2012</a></li>
                <li><a href="/awards/professional/2011" title="2011">2011</a></li>
                <li><a href="/awards/professional/2010" title="2010">2010</a></li>
                <li><a href="/awards/professional/archive" title="Archive">Archive</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li>
            <p class="intro">Student Awards</p>
            <p>Creatives the world over value the Wild Lion Media Student Awards above any other. Winning a Wild Lion Media Student Award truly marks you out as one of the best. Take your first step in becoming a creative superstar.</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/awards/student" title="Student">Student</a></li>
                <li class="new"><a href="/awards/student/2012" title="2012">2012</a></li>
                <li><a href="/awards/student/2011" title="2011">2011</a></li>
                <li><a href="/awards/student/2010" title="2010">2010</a></li>
                <li><a href="/awards/student/archive" title="Archive">Archive</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>      </li>
        <li id="nav-talent"><a class="nav-item" href="/talent" title="Talent">Talent</a>
            <div class="subnav">
    <ul class="subnav">
        <li><a href="/talent/spotlights" title="Spotlights">Spotlights</a></li>
        <li><a href="/talent/portfolios" title="Portfolios">Portfolios</a></li>
        <li><a href="/talent/new-blood" title="New Blood">New Blood</a></li>
<!--    <li><a href="/talent/graduate-placement-scheme" title="Graduate Placement Scheme">Graduate Placement Scheme</a></li>-->
        <li><a href="/talent/graduate-academy" title="Graduate Academy">Graduate Academy</a></li>
<!--        <li><a href="/talent/jobs" title="Jobs">Jobs</a></li>-->
        <li class="feature">
            <a href="/talent/graduate-academy" title="Graduate Academy - Where the creatively brave shine"><img src="#" alt="Graduate Academy - Where the creatively brave shine" class="fullpic" /></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
        </li>
        <li id="nav-learning"><a class="nav-item" href="/learning" title="Learning">Learning</a>
            <div class="subnav">
    <ul class="subnav">
        <li><a href="/learning/case-studies" title="Case Studies">Case Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="/learning/commentary" title="Commentary">Commentary</a></li>
        <li><a href="/learning/guides" title="Guides">Guides</a></li>
        <li><a href="/learning/talks" title="Talks">Talks</a></li>
        <li class="new"><a href="/learning/projects" title="Projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="/learning/workshops" title="Workshops">Workshops</a></li>
        <li><a href="/learning/professional-development" title="Professional Development">Professional Development</a></li>
        <li class="feature">
            <a href="/dandad/join/d-ad-education-network" title="University Network. Behind you all the way."><img src="#" alt="Education Network Membership. One yellow pencil. Lots of benefits." class="fullpic" /></a>

                    </li>
    </ul>
</div>      </li>
        <li id="nav-search">
            <form action="/search" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <p><label for="search">Search</label><input type="text" name="q" value="Search" id="search" class="tfield" tabindex="5" /></p>
                <p><input type="submit" id="search_submit" value="Go" tabindex="6" /></p>
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>      <div id="content">




<div class="panel-10">
    <p class="widget-title">Services</p>
    <ul class="powerlinks pl-feature extended">
    <li class="first">
        <img src="/wildlion/wp-content/themes/child/images/video_production.jpg" width="176" height="104" alt="Video Production" title="" />


        <p>
            <a href="#">
                <span>
                    <strong>Video Production</strong>
                </span>
            </a>
        </p>
        <p class="extended">
            <a href="#">
                <span>
                    Every element of your production can be designed to meet your needs.
                </span>
            </a>
        </p>
            </li>
    <li>
        <img src="/wildlion/wp-content/themes/child/images/talking_heads.jpg" width="176" height="104" alt="Talking Heads" title="" />


        <p>
            <a href="#">
                <span>
                    <strong>Talking Heads</strong><br/>
                </span>
            </a>
        </p>
        <p class="extended">
            <a href="#">
                <span>
                    A simple but effective way of communicating a message and introducing key players.
                </span>
            </a>
        </p>
            </li>
    <li>
        <img src="/wildlion/wp-content/themes/child/images/motion_graphics.jpg" width="176" height="104" alt="Motion Graphics" title="" />


        <p>
            <a href="#">
                <span>
                    <strong>Motion Graphics</strong><br/>
                </span>
            </a>
        </p>
        <p class="extended">
            <a href="#">
                <span>
                    Whether 2D logo design or 3D animation and visual effects, anything is possible.
                </span>
            </a>
        </p>
            </li>
    <li class="last">
        <img src="/wildlion/wp-content/themes/child/images/web_videos.jpg" width="176" height="104" alt="Web Videos" title="" />


        <p>
            <a href="#">
                <span>
                    <strong>Web Videos</strong><br/>
                </span>
            </a>
        </p>
        <p class="extended">
            <a href="#">
                <span>
                    From social networks to blogs and news feeds, get your viral out there.
                </span>
            </a>
        </p>
            </li>
    <li class="first">
        <img src="/wildlion/wp-content/themes/child/images/live_events.jpg" width="176" height="104" alt="Live Events" title="" />


        <p>
            <a href="#">
                <span>
                    <strong>Live Events</strong><br/>
                </span>
            </a>
        </p>
        <p class="extended">
            <a href="#">
                <span>
                    Why limit your audience to the venue capacity? Capture your event in style.
                </span>
            </a>
        </p>
            </li>
</ul>
            </div>

<div class="panel-10">
    <div class="panel-8 alpha">




    <div class="panel-2 alpha">



            </div>
</div>
        </div>

<div class="panel-10" id="footer">
    <div class="panel-2">

        <p>&copy; 2012 Wild Lion Media Limited </p>

    </div>

    <div class="panel-2" id="back-to-top">
        <p><a href="#header">Back to the top</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clearing"></div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: So only the menu is missing? What kind of content are you expecting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On line 5 of your stylesheet you have:

```
    #nav, 
    #hud, 
    #hud-toggler, 
    #imagebar, 
    #jump, 
    div #breadcrumb, 
    #quick-jump, 
    #sitemap, 
    #external-links, 
    #back-to-top, 
    ul.powerlinks, 
    ul.article-nav, 
    #sidenav ul, 
    p.return, 
    a.doc-pdf, 
    a.doc-word, 
    div.logo a {
        display: none;
}
```

This is causing everything to be hidden.  Remove that line and you'll see your content.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's resolved the issue

Answer (score 4):

In your style.css (line 5) you have a rule:

```
#nav, #hud, #hud-toggler, #imagebar, #jump, div #breadcrumb, #quick-jump, #sitemap, #external-links, #back-to-top, ul.powerlinks, ul.article-nav, #sidenav ul, p.return, a.doc-pdf, a.doc-word, div.logo a {
    display: none;
}
```

It hides all your content.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's resolved the issue